# How to detect and get the checkbox/select box (html tags) values in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I wanted to know how can I detect the checkbox values and selectbox entered in my registration form.
This is the select:

`<p><label for="favorite">שחקן המועדף עליך</label>
        <select name = "favor">
        <option> </option>
        <option value="פרקינס">דורון פרקינס</option>
        <option value="סופוקליס שחורציאניטיס">סופוקליס שחורציאניטיס</option>
        <option value="עומרי כספי">עומרי כספי</option>
        <option value="דייויד בלו">דייויד בלו</option>
        </select></p>`

and that's the checkbox:

```
 <p><label for="checkbox">אופנוע</label><input type="checkbox" name="bike" id="bike" value="bike" /> </p>
    <p><label for="checkbox">מכונית</label><input type="checkbox" name="car" id="car" value="car" /> </p>
```

How can I get the selected option and the selected boxes in the checkbox on clientside?

If anything is needed to explain let me know please,
Thank you!

**Edit:** I will explain myself a bit more, I'm having a registration form, which has checkboxes and  tags. I want to know what the client chose and insert it into my SQL DB, I need to know how to get what the client pressed, like on what box he ticked V, what option he chose.

Comment: @TimSchmelter No it isn't I'm using the regular one.

Comment: If you need to access the checkbox on serverside, us a serverside [CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox_methods.aspx) instead or at least make it `runat=server`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have to get it off client side. I know it something with going a for loop.

Comment: Then mention that in the first place. Edited your question accordingly. Can you show what you've tried? And try to explain better what you need since it's not clear(edit your question). What does _"detect the checkbox values and selectbox entered"_ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get this **client-side**, you can use jQuery to harvest the results:

```
$("#bike").is(':checked');
```

and

```
$("option:selected","#favor").val();
```

Note that your select doesn't have an id, only a name, so you'll also need to change it to this:

```
<select name="favor" id="favor">
```

If you want to get this **server-side**, you can use something like this:

```
string s = Request.Form["bike"];
if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ) {
```

Note that most browsers will send a post value if the checkbox is checked with a value of "checked" or "true", and not send it if it isn't checked.

Even better is to replace these html tags with asp.net webforms tags like so:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="bike" runat="server" ... />
```

That way you can do this server-side:

```
bool checked = this.bike.Checked;
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood me, I meant to get the values with asp.net.

Comment: like: string favorplayer =  Reqest.Params["favor"]; << it doesn't work

Comment: The unclarity of your question is yielding answers you're not expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to try implementing it tmw, but still I don't know how to get the <select> info, like what option the client chose (you explained the checkbox).

Comment: In your markup: <asp:DropDownList id="favor" runat="server"> then list your options.  In the code-behind: this.favor.SelectedValue (which may be null if they didn't select anything -- check this.favor.SelectedIndex > -1).